# Is it overkill to use a Queue and Event in Python threading?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a situation where I want one process to listen for messages over a wire. Because some messages might take longer than others to process, or need to be processed differently, I'd like my listener to just stick the messages into one or more queues.

My question is about the processes that consume those queues. I know it's a bad idea to have busy waiting, and using time.sleep seems hacky and error prone. So it seems like I should do something like:

```
def global_listener(queue, event)
    while True:
        message = wait_for_message()
        queue.put(message)
        if not event.is_set():
            event.set()

def queue_listener(queue, event):
    while True:
        event.wait()
        while not Queue.empty():  # assume no other threads are consuming it
            message = queue.get()
            process_message(message)
```

So my question is, is it appropriate to use an event just to signal that something has been put in a queue?

Comment: Why not just use `queue.get()`?  By default it blocks without a timeout, but you can provide a timeout if you need.

Comment: Oh, right. I knew something was silly about that. Thanks. If you want to put that in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`Queue.get`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.get):

```
def queue_listener(queue, tmo=None):
    while True:
        while not queue.empty():  # Had a small typo here too, use instance method
            try:
                # Default is blocking with no timeout
                message = queue.get(block=True, timeout=tmo)
                process_message(message)
            except Empty:
                # Empty exception indicates timeout was reached
                pass
```

It's basically a built-in `Event` object.

Comment: `while not queue.empty()` and `timeout` do *nothing* here. You could use: `for message in iter(queue.get, None): process(message)` instead of the whole `while True` loop.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian The `while not queue.empty()` may not do anything, but I included it in case it was necessary in OP's code.  The `timeout` certainly does do something, if it isn't `None`.  I wanted to include an example of its usage in case OP could use it as well.  Providing a timeout to this function will change its behavior.

Comment: "here" refers to the code in your answer. `timeout` if it is not `None` raises `Empty` exception that is ignored so there is no difference from the code that just blocked on `queue.get` (+/- signal handling). Unfortunately the code from StackOverflow is often copy-pasted without understanding what it does. Do *not* write code that just *might* be useful *someday* -- YAGNI.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I am fully aware what this particular code does. It will be well behaved whether or not a timeout is provided, so there is no harm if someone copy/pastes this. If I included the timeout parameter but did not wrap it in the try then I would consider this a poor code example, but I think that the combination of writing it safely and including some comments explaining the behavior is sufficient even for a beginner looking for a quick fix to their problem. If you still find issue with it feel free to edit my answer to make it more clear that error handling should be performed there.